# How to get directions in iOS 6 on new Apple Maps?

Tags: google-maps, navigation, ios6, mapkit

I've an app builded for iOS < 6, and before it all the features work perfectly. Now I've used a switch that recognizes the iOS installed on a device and then my app opens the correct maps to get directions from the local position to another (some pins on the map). The problem is that before iOS 6, the app opens the native maps and show the route to the user. Now, If the device uses iOS 6, the app opens the Apple Maps but shows a pop-up with something like "Impossible to get direction between this 2 positions". Why? Can someone helps me to solve this problem?

Here how I pass the coordinate to maps from a disclosure button:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
         NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr=Posizione attuale", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude,view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
         NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }

    else {
        NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr=Posizione attuale", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude,view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Whilst you can use the URL method for maps (`http://maps.apple.com/...`), I've found it not to be great when presenting specific locations. Your best bet would be to use MapKit objects on iOS 6 and above.

Example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = ...;
location.longtitude = ...;

MKPlacemark* placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location addressDictionary:nil];

MKMapItem* item = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
//... Any Item customizations

NSDictionary* mapLaunchOptions = ...;
[item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:mapLaunchOptions];
```

This will open Apple Maps directly, with the item you have provided.

In order to deal with directions, use the `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey` launch option, and provide the start and end map items via:

```
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Comment: @AlessandroBava If this was suitable for your needs, can you please accept the answer? Thank you

Comment: There's only a support for route between 2 places according to Apple docs. So, it looks like currently there's no alternative for Google Maps API with optimize waypoints for many locations. So, the only way is to show or open Google maps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the other answer, you have two options when giving directions: driving or walking. Here are the ways to do each one:

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude) addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];

//This is for driving
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[destination] launchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

//This is for walking
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[destination] launchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking}];
```

More info from [Apple's docs over here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html).